# Is it possible to find changes for entities that reference another entity?

Tags: javers

I have a Project entity, which is referenced by many other types of entities, for example House and Street. In Javers is it possible to construct a query that would find changes for all entities that belong to a certain project, i.e. reference that project entity?

```
class Project {
    @Id Long id;
}

class House {
    @Id Long id;
    Project project;
    String name;
}

class Street {
    @Id Long id;
    Project project;
    String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Javers isn't a relational database, there are no joins between Entities. All you can do is to change the mapping, and map House and Street as Value Objects. If so, they would be part of the Project Entity and they would be querable using Project Id.

Answer (score 0):

It possible with [commit-property-filter](https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#commit-property-filter) with the constraint that each time you commit the change of the entity belong to Project, provide the project id and the corresponding name in the commit property (e.g: projectId, 1).

In case you are using Javers with SpringBoot and track changes through JaversSpringDataJpaAuditableRepositoryAspect then here's the hint for you [Is there possibility to provide object dependent map for CommitPropertiesProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518008/is-there-possibility-to-provide-object-dependent-map-for-commitpropertiesprovide)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to always have a change on the outer entity (which would be `House` and `Street` in your case). This way, JaVers dutifully records a new snapshot, even if just `Project` changes.

To minimize the storage impact of the "always, but fake change", I created an `int f` field on the outer entity that I toggle between `0` and `1`. With `0`, it's even not part of the JSON snapshot data. To figure out which one it should be, I read in the last snapshot and get the old value there. The alternative is to always create a random number here. That uses a bit more space in the JSON, but it saves you from the database queries to retrieve the last snapshot.